# Is there a library to take a string, and classify it into a category based on whether it matches a group of strings?

Tags: java, text-classification

So, I have four lists of strings, each list which corresponds to a specific category. Each string is a job title, such as "web-developer", which corresponds to the category "IT".

The input string is going to be another job title, and the idea is to sort that job title into the appropriate category based on how well it matches the list of strings

Does anyone know a good library to accomplish this? Sadly, I do not have enough source material to properly train a machine learning system... All the libraries I've found so far seem to be based on machine learning

Alternatively, if no such library exists, do anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this? My best idea so far have been to just... search through all the strings and do a string.contains(searchString) and just match it like that. I dunno how to handle multiple matches though...

Ideally the library should be java, but this is not a necessity.

Answer (score 1):

> Alternatively, if no such library exists, do anyone have any
>   suggestions on how to accomplish this? My best idea so far have been
>   to just... search through all the strings and do a
>   string.contains(searchString) and just match it like that. I dunno how
>   to handle multiple matches though...

You could use an algorithm like Levenshtein string distance to achieve this. The algorithm gives you the number of steps needed to change one string to another: the less steps needed, the more similar the strings are.

There is an [implementation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence) within the StringUtils Apache Commons library.

Comment: This seems like an interesting way to solve my problem without using a library (directly, at least). Thank you!